# How to call a stored procedure using select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I have call statement like

```
 CALL report_procedure
('2013-02-01',now(),'2015-01-01','1');
```

and i want to use it in a select query.
i have tried like

```
Select * from ( CALL report_procedure
    ('2013-02-01',now(),'2015-01-01','1'));
```

but error occurs.
like

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ( CALL report_procedure
>           ('2013-02-01',now(),'2015-01-01','1') at line 3 0.297 sec

Can anyone suggest me a method to call stored procedure in Select statement in mysql??

Comment: Posting the error you get might help ppl solving this.

Comment: This is because MySQL doesn't allow procedure call inside select statements. Please share your objective which you want to achieve with the procedure.

Comment: Actually i need to use conditions for result of the call statement i.e. result of the stored procedure. if i can store the result in a  variable or use the call statement in select query i will be able to use conditions  for the stored procedure

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not possible to use result set from procedure in FROM clause. MySQL does not allow doing this.

You may populate another table (or temporary table) in your procedure, and after, use that table in SELECT commands -

```
CALL report_procedure ('2013-02-01',now(),'2015-01-01','1'); -- fill temp_table
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

Comment: you can just use a function instead of a sproc if you want to call it from a select

Answer (score -4):

--Firstly your store procedure should look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE report_procedure(
IN d1 DATE,
dnow DATE,
d2 DATE,
val INT
) 
BEGIN SELECT * 
FROM yourtablename
WHERE date1 = d1
AND datenow > dnow
AND date2 > d2
AND value = val;

END
--The store procedure contains the select statement.

-- then you can call the store procedure like that:
 CALL report_procedure('2013-02-01',now(),'2015-01-01','1');

--hope it helps
```

Comment: What this post wanted to SELECT from resultset of the CALL