# In SQL, how can you manipulate the fields from a CALL?

Tags: mysql, sql, call

In my code (in Delphi, using MySQL) there is an SQL request posted to the database, that is a CALL. It gets back a result set with a number of rows and columns.

If I were getting data back from a table or view, I could limit and manipulate the fields in the SELECT, but I have not found a way to do that with CALL to some procedure.

Is there some syntax that I have missed?

Comment: You can `SELECT` from a call or just deal with this in your application layer.

Comment: The point is to avoid dealing with it in the application. Specifically, I have functions that work on the first field returned, and normally I have a single field in the SELECT clause.  I have tried SELECT DATA FROM (CALL ... and SELECT DATA FROM CALL and a number of other things, and I get "error in your SQL syntax" messages in every case.

Comment: Sometimes the application is the best way to deal with it. In any case, what about [solutions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118033/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-using-select-statement-in-mysql)?